# Approximate using the central limit theorem

Tags: statistics

This is a homework question in a class I'm TAing, and I just wanted to make sure I'm not doing anything wrong, before I conclude for sure that the book has an error.

---

*Suppose $S_n$ is binomially distributed with parameters $n=200$ and $p=0.3$. Use the central limit theorem to find an approximation for $\mathbb{P}(99 \leq S_n \leq 101)$ (without the "histogram correction").*

---

The variance is $200(.21) = 42$, so

$$\mathbb{P}(99 \leq S_n \leq 101)= \mathbb{P}\left( \frac{99 - 60}{\sqrt{42}} \leq \frac{S_n - 60}{\sqrt{42}} \leq \frac{101-60}{\sqrt{42}} \right),$$

which if we use a normal approximation, is a very small number, something like $10^{-3}$. The text apparently gives an answer like $.12$. This is an error, right?

Comment: I'm confused... isn't the mean $60$?

Comment: You have some wrong numbers, for example the mean is $60$. Also, I would calculate $\Pr(W\le 101)-\Pr(W\le 98)$ where $W$ is the approximating normal (well, I am lying, I would use the continuity correction, but we have been told not to).

Comment: @Braindead Indeed! Whoops

Comment: @AndréNicolas It is still far too small, though, right?

Comment: The matlab function binopdf allows one to evaluate the probability directly using the binomial distribution. The answer it gives is approximately $5.6\times 10^{-9}$. So it would appear that your answer and the text are both wrong, but yours is closer.

Comment: Sure, lots of standard deviation units away. Can't happen.

Comment: Yes, in fact your normal approximation is about $7.58 \times 10^{-10}$.  The actual answer using the binomial distribution is about $5.637 \times 10^{-9}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error may be in stating $p=0.3$, since instead using $p=0.5$ leads to $$\Phi\left(\frac{101-100}{\sqrt{50}}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{99-100}{\sqrt{50}}\right) \approx 0.112463.$$

Of course a continuity correction would be better as $\Phi\left(\frac{101.5-100}{\sqrt{50}}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{98.5-100}{\sqrt{50}}\right) \approx 0.167996$ while $\frac1{2^{200}}\left({200 \choose 99}+{200 \choose 100}+{200 \choose 101}\right) \approx 0.167930$ showing that close to the mean the Gaussian approximation can be quite good.